# Cannot Exceed 7 Columns in Latex Table

Tags: charts, latex, tex

I am working on creating a table in LaTeX that is 8 columns wide. However, it only allows me to create so that it is 7 columns wide, and then it wraps the header of the 8th column to the next row. I tried rotating the table so that it was in landscape instead of portrait mode, but this did not fix the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd probably just need to specify 8 columns instead of the 7 your image shows - but without a copyable code, that's just a guess

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you so much! Your suggestion worked!